# Сравнение двух строк

Tags: php

Есть две переменные

```
$activebefore = 'no';
$activeafter = 'yes';
```

Как их сравнить?

Comment: @Tchort, а кто будет учить синтаксис ЯП?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотря как вам их сравнить нужно?
Если по значениям, то так :

```
<?php

if ($activebefore == $activeafter){

echo 'они равны';

} else {

echo 'Не равны';

}

?>
```

Comment: однако после [обсуждения в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35843146#35843146) я выяснил, что, например, выражение  `"0e100500" == "0e9000"` является истиным

Comment: @mymedia используй одинарные кавычки. Ну а по факту, то, скорее всего, для сравнения их приводят в тип данных INT, var_dump((int) '0e100500'); var_dump((int) '0e9000');

Answer (score 2):

```
$isLoginned = true;

if (strlen(strval($isLoginned)) == 4) {
} else {
}
```

Для самых злых проверок можешь извратиться так!

взято в **говнокода**! Этой записи 3 года, когда я её впервые увидел.

Пользуйся наздоровье, если поймешь как :)

PS если реально поймешь как.

pps если вообще вникнешь в суть!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!strcmp($activebefore,$activeafter))
{
echo "строки равны";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция определения похожести строк

```
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.similar-text.php
```